# Linguistic term for a type of reply

Tags: single-word-requests, linguistics

just wondering what the word or phrase is for a reply that indirectly answers the following way:

> Mum: Could you please do your homework?
>
> **Child: I've already done my homework.**

So, the child isn't answering the question being asked directly, yet his response is fitting.

Thanks

Comment: A _valid response_?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I don't consider "Could you please do your homework?" to be a question. It is more a polite command, a gentle way of saying "Do your homework!"

If you omit the "please," it could be interpreted as a true question: "Were you able to do your homework?". "I've already done my homework" would not be a fitting response.